# On Vim, error running simplest python code

Tags: python, vim

I'm new to Vim. I'm trying to run python codes i'm 100% sure about through space-l-r and what I get is

[Running] python - STDIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               File "", line 1                                                                                                                                                    [Running] python - STDIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: I think running from within python interpreter can cause that, can you open a different terminal and try to run python yourprogram.py  instead? I mean without using vim, you are just using the command in the wrong place I believe

Comment: The same stuff that i flawlessly run from atom or sublime got me that error, not to mention  the simple print("Hello world").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running SpaceVim from you mentioning the `SPC l r` shortcut to run the current program.

Also, it looks like you're writing Python 3 code, from your comment indicating a simple `print("Hello, World")` is failing.

SpaceVim defaults to Python 2, so that's probably why you're getting a syntax error when you try to run your code.

Add the following line to the start of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

SpaceVim will recognize that line and use the Python interpreter referred by that line when running your script.

Comment: Thank you very much, i had imagined this kind of issue but i was unfamiliar with spacevim config.